# Get result from REG QUERY

Tags: batch

I run below script to get the Symantec Endpoint Protection version but I just want to achieve the version number only. What should be rectified ?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    
For /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\currentversion\public-opstate" /v "DeployRunningVersion"') do echo %%A
PAUSE
```

[image]

Comment: Extensively: `FOR ... DO SET tmp=%%A` and then `echo %tmp%`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use powershell as a one liner from my batch file.
I do it all the time for things that suck to get to from cmd.exe.

As in (out of one of my .bat files):
`for /f %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd__HH-mm-ss"') do ECHO %%a`

Try this (because it works FOR SURE):

```bat
@echo off
SetLocal

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\Colors\' -Name ActiveBorder"') do Set ActiveBorder=%%a
echo ActiveBordervalues are %ActiveBordervalues%

EndLocal
```

I don't use Symantec Endpoint Protection so I can't actually query your key, but if I did.. I would try something like...

```bat
@echo off
SetLocal

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\currentversion\public-opstate' -Name DeployRunningVersion"') do Set DeployRunningVersion=%%a
echo DeployRunningVersion is %DeployRunningVersion%

EndLocal
```

If you need the individual 1.2.3.4, set your "tokens=4 delims=." and read %%a, %%b, %%c, and %%d

Yep, right there inline in your batch file. :)

If you try to use special queries that use batch no-no delims like | or inner quotes, you will need to mess with your query by escaping them. It can be a real PITA to figure out within the for loop (that needs 'command').

Good Luck!
I hope it works.